# How can I exclude users who have only purchase with car?

Tags: sql

There is this SQL(from Django) query:

```
SELECT "id", "name" 
FROM "polls_client" INNER JOIN "polls_purchases" 
ON ("id" = "client_id") 
WHERE "polls_purchases"."product" IN (car, bike)
```

We need to select from query users who have purchase records only `'car'`. I want to do this in one select to the database. How do I do this?

Comment: Show example input data and desired end result. "remove users who have purchase records and car and bike" is not clear. Do you want to exclude them from the query or delete them from the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can group by client and set the condition in the `HAVING` clause:

```
SELECT pc.id, pc.name 
FROM polls_client pc INNER JOIN polls_purchases pp 
ON pc.id = pp.client_id 
GROUP BY pc.id, pc.name
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN pp.product <> 'car' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Comment: `COUNT(DISTINCT ...)` is not sargable.

Comment: This query also displays people who only bought a bike, but I need only people with car

Comment: @Fyzzys Isn't this that you want? People who bought only car or only bike?

Comment: @forpas I'm sorry, I misspelled it. I want to bring out people who only bought a car

Comment: The query works for any number of  purchases. It returns only the users that bought only cars.

Answer (score 1):

> We need to select from query users who have purchase records only 'car'.

The simplest, most efficient method should be `not exists`:

```
SELECT c.*
FROM "polls_client" c
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM "polls_purchases" pp
                  WHERE c."id" = pp."client_id" AND pp."product" <> 'car'
                 );
```

In particular, this can take advantage of an index on `polls_purchases(client_id, product)`.

I would also dissuade your from using double quotes for identifies.  They only serve to clutter queries.